# Прикрепление фотографии с помощью wall.post - Python / vkontakte-api

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-2.7

Наткнулся на такую проблему, что бот не может прикрепить картинку, присланную ему в лс, к посту при использовании `wall.post`. Её адрес (`owner_id, id, access_key`) подхватывается, но на стену почему-то не постится. Причём, для тех же видео такой проблемы нет, всё нормально публикуется. Кроме того, если не указать текст сообщения поста, или указать его пустым, выведется следующая ошибка:

> ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: invalid message param

А если указать его, опубликуется лишь текст, без картинки, т.е. как будто бы я не отправлял параметр `attachments` вообще.
Опять же, для видео таких проблем нет.
Бот авторизуется как пользователь, а не сообщество, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Сейчас заметил, что фотографии из альбомов прикрепляются, но пересланные кнопкой "Поделиться" - всё равно нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, мне ответила техподдержка. Ответ прост - приватные фото нельзя отправлять на стену, нужно пересохранять в открытый альбом